# How to channel all traffic to tor on linux

Tags: linux, tor

I am new to tor and Kali linux, I have installed Kali linux and installed tor and download tor bundle, but I realised only when I brows through the tor bundle browser is when my traffic is being channel through tor, excluding any other browser and application.

How can I channel all my network traffic on linux to pass through the tor network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to torrc:

```
AutomapHostsOnResolve  1
DNSPort                53530
TransPort              9040
```

create a file to contain your iptables rules. For IPv4: `/etc/iptables.firewall.rules` and for IPv6: `/etc/ip6tables.firewall.rules`.

Now edit the IPv4 file and add something like the following (make sure to grep for TODO items and follow the instructions):

```
# Ues the nat table to redirect some traffic to Tor

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Don't allow Tor traffic to get stuck in a redirect loop...
# TODO: Is `tor' your actual Tor user? It might be `debian-tor' or `toranon' or something else.
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tor -j RETURN

# Redirect DNS lookups to Tor.
# TODO: Set this to your Tor DNSPort if it's not 53530.
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53530

# Do not redirect private networks or loopback.
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN

# Redirect HS connections to the TransPort.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.192.0.0/10 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040

# Redirect all TCP traffic to Tor's TransPort.
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040

COMMIT

# Only accept anonymized network traffic in the filter table.

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LAN - [0:0]

# Allow loopback
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow connections that are already established.
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Reject incoming connections.
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

# Accept network traffic for the Tor service itself.
# TODO: Tor user?
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tor -j ACCEPT

# Accept DNS requests to the Tor DNSPort.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53530 -j ACCEPT

# Accept outgoing traffic to the local Tor TransPort.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9040 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Accept outgoing traffic to the local Tor SOCKSPorts.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9150 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Accept connections on private networks.
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j LAN
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j LAN
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j LAN
-A LAN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LAN -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LAN -j ACCEPT

# Reject all other outgoing traffic.
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

COMMIT
```

For the IPv6 file, you can do something similar with ip6tables, or just drop all IPv6 traffic.

Now set these rules to be loaded on startup by creating the file `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/firewall` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
/sbin/ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables.firewall.rules
```

Restart Tor if needed, and load your new firewall rules manually by executing the previous commands.